# Ошибка :PARSE ERROR:Error:unsupported class file version 52.0

Tags: java, android

Вылазит вот такая ошибка Error:unsupported class file version 52.0. Чем она вызвана и как её исправить?

Comment: Какой версией `BuildTools` вы пользуетесь? Такая ошибка возникает при использовании версии `24.0.0`. Если вы используете `24.0.0`, то переключитесь на `23.0.3`

Comment: И опять вы задаете свой вопрос несколько раз. Такое делать **запрещено**.

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего, вы пытаетесь запустить ваше приложение на Java версии ниже, чем та, под которую компилировались классы. Попробуйте обновить версию Java до 8